# Spacing Between Cells in CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a collection view with custom cells in my xib. All the cells are exactly 45 x 45. The image that fills the view is also exactly 45 x 45 in the cell. All the spacing and insets are set to 0 in my xib and also with the code below. My question is, why is there still a small space between the cells? Thanks!

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly 45 x number of cells in each row does not equal to the width of the screen.

Comment: Thanks dude.. Your question is my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set the minimum spacing, but not the actual spacing between cells. So, unless the collection view is an even multiple of 45, then there will be spaces added by the system.

Comment: just wondering, how would we get that spacing value?